# How to convert PCM data to Hexadecimal Data

Tags: c, linux

I'm developing an application which reads a microphone and stores the PCM data in a buffer and I want to convert the buffer to a hexadecimal values and manipulate it.
 Basically I want to implement xxd functionality in my C Program.
I'm able to do it manually, by writing the PCM data in a file(file.pcm) and then using 
"xxd -r file.c >> file.h". This will give the hexadecimal data in a structure and the length.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to convert hexadecimal data into a hexadecimal string? Like from "Hello world" (its hex representation is `[0x68, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64]`) to "68656C6C6F20776F726C64" ?

Comment: Basically I record a stream from the mic and store it in a file as raw data, I want that raw data to be converted to HexaDecimal Data

Comment: @wjdoss: Hexadecimal is simply a way to represent raw data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm going to assume that you want hex to hex-string "conversion" then.

Here is the code take some input from stdin and write it as hex data into a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fd = NULL;            // File descriptor.
    unsigned char c  = '\0';    // Character.
    int status = 0;             // fread() status.

    if(argv[1] == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Usage: %s <file name>\n",
            argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    fd = fopen(argv[1], "w");
    if(fd == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
        "Error: cannot write to file %s.\n",
        argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    for(status = fread(&c, 1, 1, stdin);
        c != EOF && status != 0;
        status = fread(&c, 1, 1, stdin)
    )
    {
        char buff[2];
        sprintf(buff, "%02X", (unsigned char)c);
        c = 0;
        fwrite(buff, 1, 2, fd);
    }

    fclose(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note a few things tho:

1. The string put in the file is continuous. No newlines (since newlines from input will be converted to `0x0A`, `0x0D` or both). If you want to add formatting, please add a counter, and write spaces and newlines (and or else) to your files according to the value of the counter (for example, `if( !((i+1) % 16) ) { buff[0] = '\n'; fwrite(buff, 1, 1, fd); }` after the `fwrite(buff, 1, 2, fd);` line).
2. if you want to use xxd on the generated file, please add a new line after 16 chars have been read from input. Additionally, you will need to add the offset at the start of each line.
3. Last but not the least, the converstion from data to hex-string is done at the `sprintf` line. It 'prints into the string' (sprintf) `buff` the `char c` interpreted as *"two digits zero-left-padded uppercase hexadecimal"*

Comment: This is a good example. Some operating systems already contain a tool for converting raw data into hexadecimal, for example `hd` or `hexdump`. Some operating systems have a hexadecimal editor as well. Also, reading and writing one character at a time might be less efficient than converting whole chunks. Also, the `(char)c` cast in the `sprintf` call is unnecessary, it will be promoted to `int` anyway. Also, `%x` (and `%X`) expect **`unsigned int`**.

Comment: You're right, but I've written this code to be easy to read and understand. And so, I've added an unnecessary cast to remind the reader the type of the variable (and the reader has not to care about what printf does internally ;)). Same for using a char and not a string: it's easier to read (and easy to improve) and avoids unnecessary difficulties (like handling pointers). I have corrected the code to use an `unsigned char` instead of a `char`, since %x|%X implies the use of an `unsigned int`.